# Why am I getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) message?

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int count = argc;
    string key = argv[1];
    int keylength = strlen(key);

    if (keylength < 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters\n");
    }
    else if (argc < 1)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Every time I call the program with "./substitution" and no other command line arguments, it gives me the message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I just wanted it to print back the line describing what the user should be putting in. Does anyone understand why this is happening?

Comment: Check `argc` first, before you try to use `argv[1]`.

Comment: If you don't give any arguments to the command, `strlen(key)` fails because `argv[1]` is a null pointer.

Comment: `argc` will never be `< 1`... Not in this universe...

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what was going wrong. I was able to fix it. I appreciate the advice Barmar.

Comment: What would happen if user types 42 characters as the key?

Comment: Depending on the age of the compiler, as written above, not all "paths" lead to a `return` statement... This would give errors (if the compiler is "older" and didn't "fill-in" the absent `return 0;` before the closing brace of `main()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // int count = argc; // unnecessary duplication
    string key = argv[1]; // Too optimistic
    int keylength = strlen(key); // undefined behaviour when no "argument" supplied

    /* already "off the rails */
    /* ... */
}
```

Perform operations in a reasonable sequence

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for 'exit()'
#include <string.h>
#include "cs50.h" // EDIT. Required for "string" datatype

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); // <<** called "early termination"
    }
    // When "flow" has been redirected with
    // exit(), return, break, continue or goto
    // PLEASE do not write a pointless "else" clause.
    // Any code that follows IS the "else" condition.

    if( strlen( argv[1] ) != 26 ) // ONLY 26 is acceptable
    {
        printf("Key must contain ONLY 26 unique alphabetic characters\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    string key = argv[1];

    /* more code */

    return 0;
}
```

There could be less code by combining two checks (in the correct sequence!), providing the erring user with useful information.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if( argc != 2 || strlen( argv[1] ) != 26 )
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        printf("Key must contain ONLY 26 unique alphabetic characters\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); // <<** called "early termination"
    }

    /* more validation of parameter at argv[1] */

    string key = argv[1]; // now acceptable. use alias.

    /* more code */

    return 0;
}
```

Since there is more than one "check" to perform before getting into the nitty-gritty of processing, perhaps all the validation checks could be done in a function that returns go/no-go:

```
int invalidKey( string candidate ) {
    if( strlen( candidate ) != 26 )
        return 1; // bad

    /* more validation of "key" returning 1 if objectionable */

    return 0; // good; passed all the tests
}

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if( argc != 2 || invalidKey( argv[1] ) )
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        printf("Key must contain ONLY 26 unique alphabetic characters\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); // <<** called "early termination"
    }

    string key = argv[1];

    /* more code */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor suggestion: I would move `string key = argv[1];` _before_ the check on the argument's length as you can then write: `strlen(key) != 26` which is more expressive.

Comment: @Chris Yes, equally valid. Or: `#define KEY argv[1]`... To my mind, it is not a `key` until it has been shown to be a `key`... The other requirement of "all unique monocase alphabetic" should be checked, imo, before argv[1] is called a 'key'... Your suggestion is perfectly fine, too. `:-)`

Comment: So `string valid_key = argv[1];` at that position is definitely out. ;)

Comment: @Chris That would be terrific (once all the hurdles are passed) `:)` Just 'tweaked' the error message to be more helpful to the user. `:-)`

Comment: @Chris Justified my rationale (a bit) with an alternative bit of code. `:-)`

Comment: Simple non related question, why `exit` over `return`?

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT The two have exactly the same effect in this example, but I would favour `exit()` both as it **stands out** as something bad has happened, and, if the code block is moved to a subordinate function, `return` will not suffice to terminate execution. In this example, using `return` from `main()` would be ample, yes. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I call the program with "./substitution" and no other command line arguments, it gives me the message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

If there are no other arguments, then `argv[1]` yields `NULL`, which is then assigned to `key` which is passed to `strlen()`, and passing a `NULL` value to `strlen()` invokes undefined behavior.

Also `argc` will never be less than one because the command executing the program will always be the first argument. You should check if `argc < 2` **before** attempting to access the arguments.

## Correct Program:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return -1;
    }
    string key = argv[1];
    int keylength = strlen(key);
    if (keylength != 26) {
        printf("Key must contain exactly 26 characters\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In some circles, SP (0x20) is considered an "ASCII character"... Why can't I, the user, enter SP as one of the 26 characters??? :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 But you can. You can put it in quotes, or put a backslash (escape character) in front of it.